# Javascript slideshow select "next" image confusion

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm very new to javascript. the following code works fine. when I click "next" button the slideshow stops how it should do but when clicking to show previous image it shows only one picture and stops? I can't get what is wrong. help me please

```
window.onload = function () {

    newImg = new Array("images/image1.jpg", "images/image2.jpg", "images/image3.jpg", "images/image4.jpg");

    var iImage = 1;

    var imgTimer = new Timer();
    imgTimer.Interval = 5000;
    imgTimer.Tick = function () {
        document.slideshow.src = newImg[iImage];
        iImage++
        if (iImage >= newImg.length) {
            iImage = 0;
        }

        document.getElementById('next').onclick = function () {
            if (iImage < newImg.length) {
                document.slideshow.src = newImg[iImage];
                iImage++
                if (iImage = newImg.length) {
                    iImage = 0;

                }
            }
            imgTimer.Stop();
        }
        document.getElementById('prev').onclick = function () {
            if (iImage > 0) {
                document.slideshow.src = newImg[iImage];
                iImage--
                if (iImage = 0) {
                    iImage = newImg.length;
                }
            }
            imgTimer.Stop();
        }


    };
    imgTimer.Start();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This javascript cycles through the images, but if the user clicks the next or prev buttons, the auto-cycling stops.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var newImg = ["images/image1.jpg",
                  "images/image2.jpg",
                  "images/image3.jpg",
                  "images/image4.jpg"],
        iImage = 0,
        slide = document.getElementById('slideshow'),
        next = document.getElementById('next'),
        prev = document.getElementById('prev'),
        interval = 3200,
        t = null;

    next.onclick = function () {
        iImage++;
        if (iImage >=  newImg.length) {
            iImage = 0;
        }
        slide.src = newImg[iImage];
        if (t !== null) {
            clearInterval(t);
            t = null;
        }
    };

    prev.onclick = function () {
        iImage--;
        if (iImage < 0) {
            iImage = newImg.length - 1;
        }
        slide.src = newImg[iImage];
        if (t !== null) {
            clearInterval(t);
            t = null;
        }
    };

    t = setInterval( function () {
        iImage++;
        if (iImage >= newImg.length) {
            iImage = 0;
        }
        slide.src = newImg[iImage];
    }, interval);

    slide.src = newImg[iImage];
};
```

This assumes html like this:

```
<input id='prev' value='prev' type='button'/> &nbsp;
<input id='next' value='next' type='button'/> <br/>
<img id='slideshow' src='' style='width:300px;'/>
```

Comment: Thanks you made my day!!! It works !! but may be you could help me with another thing too. I'm trying to make my slideshow slide from right to left but without usage of jQuery. Was trying to look on google but no luck.